# How can I get karma browser's to use a dark theme?

Tags: javascript, css, karma-jasmine

I'm starting to use karma in an Angular app and would like to change the browser theme to be dark. I wanted to know if there was anywhere in the configuration file I can just inject simple css or use add a js file to inject these styles.

e.g. karma-styles.js

```
var css = `
  html * {
    background-color: black !important;
    color: white !important;
  }

  .html-reporter .failures .spec-detail .description {
    background-color: #b03911 !important;
  }
`,
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
```

I've tried adding the file in karma config:
    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      './karma-styles.js',
    ],

but can't seem to get it to work or am not sure if this is the appropriate place to add this file.

Does anyone know how I can get custom styles with karma for dark themes or plugins that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

I looked for premade styles for this but was unable to find any so quickly made my own and published it in a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/Neofish22/3c085929727af48ff07a1d90380f7609) as `karma.css`.

Karma allows you to add files to its config, which allows insertion of CSS or JS. [Source](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/431#issuecomment-28294234).

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'karma.css'
]
```

These are relative to the config, which would be the root of your project if you use the default setup for [Angular.io](https://angular.io).

Notably this only applies to the content of the iframe, so in lieu of having a proper plugin to do this, I directly edited the source HTML files in the node module with the following line:

```
<link type="text/css" href="base/karma.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The path `base` is where you would find the CSS file as added by the configuration above. The 2 files you should edit are (typically) here: `/node_modules/karma/static/client*.html`. I suspect relative links would work as expected here (cannot use .. freely but can go into subdirs).