# Karma puts app styles in front of reporter

Tags: angular, configuration, styles, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I'm trying to do karma test with angular-cli and the app styles I have keep getting in front of the reporter. It's a bit frustrating and I want to be remove the app styles completely.

[image]

My current fix is:

app.component.scss

```
:host /deep/ {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I don't want to have to visit this sass file and comment/uncomment out these lines of code every time I do `npm run test`.

How can I remove the app styles so I can see the actual reporter?

[A related question I also posted: Question About Dark Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404241/how-can-i-get-karma-browsers-to-use-a-dark-theme)

Answer (score 0):

My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49732323/1863646) to your other question should help: merely include your hide CSS in `karma.css` as described there. Notably you won't have to edit the original Karma HTML files for this particular functionality.

An extract from that answer:

> Karma allows you to add files to its config, which allows insertion of CSS or JS. [Source](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/431#issuecomment-28294234).
>
> ```
> // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
> files: [
>     'karma.css'
> ]
> ```
>
> These are relative to the config, which would be the root of your project if you use the default setup for [Angular.io](https://angular.io).